# Is there a way to make this code shorter? (reaction collector)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, discord.js

```
const backwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⏪' && user.id === message.author.id;
const forwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⏩' && user.id === message.author.id;
const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(backwardsFilter, {time: 90000});
const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(forwardsFilter, {time: 90000});
```

I tried to make one filter for both collectors but still have to type this `(x,y,z) => filter(x,y,z,'⏪')`

```
const filter = (reaction, user, c, emoji) => reaction.emoji.name === emoji && user.id === message.author.id;
const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector((x,y,z) => filter(x,y,z,'⏪'), {time: 90000});
const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector((x,y,z) => filter(x,y,z,'⏩'), {time: 90000});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a *higher-order function*, one that takes in the character you're looking for and returns a function that takes three arguments (`reaction`, `user`, and `c`, corresponding to your current `(x, y, x) =>`) and returns the appropriate filter operation.

Also, it doesn't look like `c` (same as `z`) is being used at all in any code here, so feel free to remove it from the argument list.

```
const makeFilter = emoji => (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === emoji && user.id === message.author.id;
const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(makeFilter('⏪'), {time: 90000});
const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(makeFilter('⏩'), {time: 90000});
```

Comment: smart solution! Thank you